# Enumerate with tabular-like characteristics

Tags: tables, indentation, enumerate

I want the text to display more like the first example, but automatically enumerate like the second one and be indented a tab away.

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
(a)& $A\cup B=\{x:x\in A$ oder $x\in B\}$& Vereinigung von $A$ und $B$\\
(b)& $A\cap B=\{x:x\in A$ und $x\in B\}$& Schnitt von $A$ und $B$\\
(c)& $A\backslash B=\{x:x\in A$ und $x\notin B\}$& Differenz, sprich "A ohne B"\\
(d)& $A\times B=\{(x,y):x\in A$ und $y\in B\}$& Kartesisches Produkt\\
& Für $A=B$ schreibe kurz $A^2$
\end{tabular}


\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item $A\cup B=\{x:x\in A$ oder $x\in B\}$ \hfill Vereinigung von $A$ und $B$
    \item $A\cap B=\{x:x\in A$ und $x\in B\}$ \hfill Schnitt von $A$ und $B$
    \item $A\backslash B=\{x:x\in A$ und $x\notin B\}$ \hfill Differenz, sprich "A ohne B"
    \item $A\times B=\{(x,y):x\in A$ und $y\in B\}$ \hfill Kartesisches Produkt \\
    Für $A=B$ schreibe kurz $A^2$ %Stand zumindest so ohne weitere Aufzählung an der Tafel... ja, echt komisch, müssen wir später in erfahrung bringen
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 4):

Similar to Zarko's solution, but a little bit more 'condensed', using `\newcolumntype`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,style=german]{csquotes}
\usepackage{array}


\newcounter{rowcntr}  % new counter for enumerating table rows
\renewcommand\therowcntr{(\alph{rowcntr})}

\newcolumntype{N}[1]{>{\raggedleft\refstepcounter{rowcntr}\therowcntr\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{N{2cm}*{2}{L{0.45\linewidth}}}
  \label{foo} & $A\cup B=\{x:x\in A$ oder $x\in B\}$          &  Vereinigung von $A$ und $B$  \tabularnewline
  & $A\cap B=\{x:x\in A$  oder $x\in B\}$           & Schnitt von $A$ und $B$\tabularnewline
  & $A\setminus B=\{x:x\in A$ und $x\notin B\}$  & Differenz, sprich \enquote{A ohne B} \tabularnewline
  & $A\times B=\{(x,y):x\in A$ und $y\in B\}$   Für $A=B$ schreibe kurz $A^2$               & Kartesisches Produkt\tabularnewline
\end{tabular*}

See \ref{foo}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{tabitem}  % new counter for enumerating table rows
\renewcommand\thetabitem{(\alph{tabitem})}
\newcommand{\getTabItem}{\refstepcounter{tabitem}\thetabitem}% rows can be labeled and referenced

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}
                             >{\getTabItem}l
                        *{2}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.45\linewidth}}
                             @{}}
    & $A\cup B=\{x:x\in A$ oder $x\in B\}$          & Vereinigung von $A$ und $B$\\
    & $A\cap B=\{x:x\in A$ und $x\in B\}$           & Schnitt von $A$ und $B$\\
    & $A\setminus B=\{x:x\in A$ und $x\notin B\}$  & Differenz, sprich "A ohne B``\\
    & $A\times B=\{(x,y):x\in A$ und $y\in B\}$
        Für $A=B$ schreibe kurz $A^2$               & Kartesisches Produkt\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code which relies on `listliketab` and `tabularx`. The rows can be cross-referenced:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, german]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx, listliketab}

    \begin{document}

\storestyleof{enumerate}
\begin{listliketab}
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}\renewcommand\thetabenum{(\alph{tabenum})}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\thetabenum}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}L >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X>{\hsize=0.8\hsize\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X @{}}
  \tabitem & $A\cup B=\{x:x\in A$ oder $x\in B\}$ & Vereinigung von $A$ und $B$\\
   \tabitem\label{row-2} & $A\cap B=\{x:x\in A$ und $x\in B\}$ & Schnitt von $A$ und $B$\\
   \tabitem & $A\setminus B=\{x:x\in A$ und $x\notin B\}$ & Differenz, sprich "A ohne B``\\
   \tabitem & $A\times B=\{(x,y):x\in A$ und $y\in B\}$
        Für $A=B$ schreibe kurz $A^2$ & Kartesisches Produkt\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{listliketab}

We read in row \ref{row-2}

\end{document}
```

[image]